# Replace substring from beginning given another string

Tags: java

I have two strings s1 & s2. I want to remove s2 from s1 if s1 starts with s2. s2 can be of variable length.

```
For eg. s1 = 123456789 s2 = 123 output = 456789
For eg. s1 = 123456789 s2 = 12345 output = 6789
```

Right now I do index calculation for s2 from s1 and then extract the substring.

I am curious is there a better way of doing this? Regular expressions?

Comment: `String output = s1.startsWith(s2) ? s1.substring(s2.length()) : s1;`.

Comment: pseudo-ish code: if (s1.substr(0,s2.length).equals(s2)) { s1=s1.substr(s2.length))`

Comment: I really don't get people's obsession for using regular expressions for things that really don't need them. What is wrong with a single call to substring() and a single call to equals()?

Comment: Because regex is essentially a do-all solution for most problems, not that I agree with using it for everything. So for many people it's a go-to solution.

Comment: @nhouser9 I don't know if you've heard the saying "everything looks like a nail when you've only got a hammer". In other words, if it's the only tool you know, it's the only tool you try to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No sense using regex for a simple substring problem. Broken down:

```
//precondition: s2.length() <= s1.length()
String piece = s1.substring(0, s2.length());
String remainder = s1.substring(s2.length());
return piece.equals(s2) ? remainder : s1;
```

Or even shorter/simplified:

```
return s1.startsWith(s2) ? s1.substring(s2.length()) : s1;
```

Comment: The first approach doesn't always work, for example if `s1` is shorter than `s2`. The second approach is correct, easier and more efficient.

Comment: It was originally a precondition, but I moved away from the one-liner to fill out the answer more for the inbetween-steps.

Answer (score -1):

In the way how you describe your problem, you want to remove s2 from s1. In fact you want to replace all occurencies of s2 in s1 with an empty string, which is done using

```
s1.replace(s2,"");
```

Or

```
 s1.replaceFirst(s2,"");
```

if you want to juste remove the first occurency of s2

Comment: Neither of these are correct. The first removes all occurrences of `s2`; the second removes the first occurrence, but not necessarily at the start of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(s1.startsWith(s2) && s1.length() > s2.length()) {
            System.out.println(s1.substring(s2.length(), s1.length()));
        }
```

Something like this perhaps?